# Engine running cold. Warms up at stop lights, drops wile driving

Tags: chevrolet, temperature, cruze

I have a 2014 Chevrolet Cruze LT that has been running cold even after letting it warm up for at least 10 minutes. This morning is was 45 degrees outside, I let the car warm up and the temperature gauge read cold for a mile drive. 
I turned off the car and turned it back on, and got a better reading still not normal, but the gauge fluctuated while driving.

The thermostat and the engine temperature sensor was changed back in may. The coolant temperature sensor on the radiator was changed very recently.

Haven't tested coolant temperature, no engine check light on. Car drives rough while reading cold.
Engine fan starts as normal at start up.

I believe the radiator coolant temperature sensor maybe faulty and need to be re-replaced. But Honestly I have not idea what's going on and could used a bit of help.

Comment: Have you checked the coolant level? No coolant means no (reliable) reading.